# Best practice for database connection in recursive function?

Tags: python, mysql, database, recursion

I have a recursive python function that processes data and needs to write data to a mysql database from within the function.

I typically connect to a mysql DB like this

```
def MyFunc(x, y):
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        user = "myuser",
        password = "SuperSecretPassword",
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        database = "MyDatabase")

    # Process some data here, then write it to the DB

    cursor = conn.cursor() 
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table a, b, c VALUES(1,2,3)")
    conn.commit()

    MyFunc(x, y)
```

While that works, if I do that within my function, I am going to create hundreds, if not thousands, of connections to my mysql database depending on how deep the recursion goes within the data I am processing.  This seems like a really bad idea.

I tried creating the connection and the cursor in the main part of my code, outside of the function, and then just referenced them from within the function like a global variable:

```
global cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table a, b, c VALUES(1,2,3)")
global conn.commit()
```

but that didn't work.

Is it possible to write to a database in python within a recursive function like this and only open 1 connection to the DB?

Comment: In Python, indentation is important in determining scope. Your declaration, " cursor = conn.cursor()", does not need to be at the top (as was mentioned in another comment), it simply needs to be unindented. More information about indentation in Python can be found here: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you keep a single connection in your Python module, e.g.:

```
# script.py

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        user = "myuser",
        password = "SuperSecretPassword",
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        database = "MyDatabase")


def MyFunc(x, y):

    # Process some data here, then write it to the DB

    cursor = conn.cursor() 
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table a, b, c VALUES(1,2,3)")
    conn.commit()

    MyFunc(x, y)
```

Comment: doh!!!  I put all my functions at the top of the script, and had the code that did the connection outside of the functions at the bottom by the main code of the script.  Apparently to use the conn from the functions and main part of the script I need to declare it at the top of the script above everything else.  Thank you!  I'm still somewhat new to python and getting used to it's quirks.